# Files missing after using mv command

Tags: files, mv

I ran

```
/$ sudo mv -f -i FileSystem/*
```

After using the command all my files are missing. Where my files have gone to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files in the globbed folder (`FileSystem`) will be treated by the shell as a list of arguments to the `mv` command, and so the last file/folder in the list will be read as the destination.

- If you had just two files, `mv` would replace the second with the first after prompting for permissions to overwrite.
- If the last item in the list returned is a folder, `mv` command will move everything else inside the folder in question.

It seems likely that the missing files are located in the last folder that the `FileSystem/*` would have produced at the time the command was run.

Consider the following test folder containing exactly two files, where running the command you listed will attempt to overwrite the first file with the second (I've added `-v` for  illustrative purposes):

```
~$ ls testdir
test1.txt  test2.txt

sudo mv -f -i -v testdir/*
mv: overwrite 'testdir/test2.txt'? y
renamed 'testdir/test1.txt' -> 'testdir/test2.txt'
```

In another scenario, where a folder is the last in the list of files, it moves everything to `test_folder` (as it's the last returned item and is treated as the destination by `mv` command) like so:

```
$ ls testdir/
empty_folder1  test1.txt  test2.txt  test_folder
```

All of your files will be moved to the last item in the list (`test_folder` in this example)

```
$ sudo mv -f -i -v testdir/*
renamed 'testdir/empty_folder1' -> 'testdir/test_folder/empty_folder1'
renamed 'testdir/test1.txt' -> 'testdir/test_folder/test1.txt'
renamed 'testdir/test2.txt' -> 'testdir/test_folder/test2.txt'
```

Comment: Thank you. I did in fact find all the missing files and directories in a folder named the same as the last one in the sources portion of the command.

Answer (score 2):

This command lacks a destination:

```
sudo mv -f -i FileSystem/*
```

Due to expansion of the `*`  `mv` will use the LAST one it finds for the directory to move it to (or file is there was only 2). Example:

```
touch 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
$ mv *
mv: target '8' is not a directory
```

It errors out because `8` is not a directory. The last one in your command probably was a directory so it will have moved all the files into that directory. Or if the `mv` consists of 2 files it will have moved one over the other.

So do a

```
ls FileSystem
```

and it should still have 1 item in there being a directory that has the result of your `mv`. Mind that due to the `-f` (force) and if it was 2 files you deleted one and will not be able to recover it. You would need to restore a backup.

Example of the last:

```
$ ls
1  2
$ mv *
$ ls
2
```

This only happens when there are TWO files.

1 errors out

```
ls
1
$ mv *
mv: missing destination file operand after '1'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
```

3 and more error out too (as with the 8 files example above) UNLESS the last one is an existing directory:

```
$ touch 1 2 3 4 5 6
$ mkdir 7
$ mv *
$ ls
7
$ ls 7
1  2  3  4  5  6
```